# Why is the username and pin sections of the database unrecognized?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

```
# PHASE 2 (With Database) SQLite 3 

# Define Connection and Cursor 
connection = sqlite3.connect('Bank_Users.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Create Users Table 
command1 = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
bank(pin INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , username text )"""
cursor.execute(command1)

# Add to Users/Bank
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES (7620, 'Kailas Kurup')")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES (4638, 'Bethany Watkins')")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES (3482, 'John Hammond')")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES (3493, 'Melissa Rodriguez')")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES (9891, 'Kevin Le')")

# Get Results / Querying Database
cursor.execute("SELECT username, pin FROM bank")
results = cursor.fetchall()
print(results)

# Check Database User Info  
def read_from_db():
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        if username in row: 
            if pin in row: 
                print ("Success")
        else: 
            print("Invalid Pin")
```

** I'm trying to check the database based on the username and pin entered. For example if a username and pin other than 7620 and Kailas Kurup was entered, it would return "Invalid". But my code is going unrecognized and there are squiggly lines under "username" and "pin". Why is this happening and how do I fix it? I am using visual studio code (VScode).

Comment: You seem to talk about the behavior of an IDE, not of Python or your program. You should mention that IDE (at least in the tags).

Comment: all your `username` and `pin` are not defined. they only appeared in sql scripts, which are still undefined in python.

Comment: where do you call `read_from_db()` and why don't you execute the SQL statement each time you search something